# Why do both [-[]] and [+[]] return [0] in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why do both [-[]] and [+[]] return [0] in Javascript?
`console.log([+[]])`
`console.log([-[]])`

Answer (score 3):

unary `+` or `-` operator just converts it operand to a number. Empty array converted to number is 0. So you got the same result for both `[+[]]` and `[-[]]`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus

https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-unary-plus-operator